# Android WebMap Popup Viewing not showing my layer info

Tags: web-mapping, layers, android, popup, arcgis-android

I used the code for WebMap Popup Viewing from ArcGIS for Developers (https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/webmap-popup-viewing/) and I just changed the map URL with a map I created and contains 4 layers.

However, every time I tap on a point where I'm supposed to get a Pop Up Dialog containing my marker's details, I see the querying message for a moment and it disappears, I don't see any info.

The application doesn't report any errors, I guess it has something to do with the way I fill in information in the layer? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Okay I fixed it by using Feature layers instead of the regular layer.